# PHP Laravel - Display a collection string in blade view

Tags: php, laravel

I have a  controller and want to display the collection to my blade view as is.

here's my code

```
public function reserveSchedule($id){
    $schedule = DB::table('schedules AS s')
                ->select('s.lesson_name AS title','s.time_start AS start','s.time_end AS end')
                ->where('s.teacher',$id)
                ->get();
    return view('pages.reserve',compact('schedule'));
}
```

in my blade view I need to display the `schedule` variable. So i did

```
{{$schedule}}
```

but it is giving me an error  `htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

I know that the collection is an array, but I need the array to be just a string of array so I can parse it as a JSON in my javascript and use it with my fullCalendar events.

Appreciate any help.

I am using Laravel 5.1 by the way.

Thanks guys!

Comment: You can use the json _encode($schedule) function to convert the array into json string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re - Edited Answer ---

If you want to parse `$schedule` as JSON, you can just `json_encode()` it before you assign it to the view.

`$schedule = json_encode($schedule);`

Comment: I know that, but I want the collection to be rendered as is.. plain array string

Comment: it's throwing an error `Call to a member function toJson() on array`

Comment: Oh, right. Since you aren't using Eloquent models, you will just get a normal array and not a Collection. Just use `json_encode()`

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 5.1, `get()` returns an array instead of a Collection, so you can either change your controller:

```
return view('pages.reserve', array('schedule' => json_encode($schedule));
```

...or you can change your view:

```
{{ json_encode($schedule) }}
```